# Configuring Apache and Tomcat: Cannot Access / On Server

Tags: apache, tomcat7, ajp

I am trying to run Apache and Tomcat7 together on a VPS host running Ubuntu Service 13.04 64 bit, but am unable to get them connected together via the AJP Connector. I've read tutorials until my eyes bled, with no luck. I have the mod-proxy-ajp module installed.

I have the AJP connector uncommented in Tomcat's server.xml file. Here is my site file from /etc/apache2/sites-available (which is symlinked to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mysite.org
    ServerAlias mysite.org

    <Proxy *>
            AddDefaultCharset Off
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Even with this, attempting to access http://www.mysite.org gives me a 403 error, message is "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Is there anything wrong with my vhost config?

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to have been a stupid question. I had made the changes to the file in /etc/apache2/sites-available, but neglected to create a symlink from there to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

Duh.